# What is it called when we interpolate a point INTO a grid...

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, interpolation, multigrid

Consider a uniform 2D grid, where each $(x,y)$ value on this grid has a corresponding value. So, if I want to find the value, $v$ (unknown) of a point that exists at some arbitrary co-ordinate $(x,y)$ (known) that exists between grid values, then I can use bilinear interpolation to find $v$, using say, the 4 closest grid points to the point $(x,y)$.

However, what if I am given $(x,y)$ as before, AND also given $v$, but I now want to "interpolate" the value of $v$, INTO the 4 closest points on the grid. That is, I want to simply figure out how much $v$ contributes into the 4 grid points closest to it.

What is that called? Is it also called "interpolation", or does this go by another name?

Comment: As I understand, interpolation is any numerical procedure that uses existing data of a function (in this case, domain-range pairs) to approximate unknown properties of the function. So I would say yes, this is still interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

This only makes sense if there is a unique $z=x+iy$ corresponding to a given $v$, and then it is interpolation of the inverse (complex or vector-valued) function.